# Git: How to remove intermediate commit?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rewrite-history

### Current Commit History

```
    O- commit C  HEAD
    |
    O- commit B 
    |
    O- commit A  ← I want to delete this commit
   /
  /  branch: feature/foo
 /
0 -- master HEAD
```

### Goal Commit History

```
    O- commit C  HEAD
    |
    O- commit B 
   /
  /  branch: feature/foo
 /
0 -- master HEAD
```

How do I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+old+commit

Comment: Indeed a duplicate. However, the accepted answer over there is totally off and the title phrasing is different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *git rebase --interactive*:

- `git rebase --interactive HEAD~3`
- This will bring up an editor containing something like this:

```
pick aaaaaaaa commit A
pick aaaaaaaa commit B
pick cccccccc commit C
```

- This show the last *3* commits (hence HEAD*~3*)
- remove the first line, so it it looks like this:

```
pick aaaaaaaa commit B
pick cccccccc commit C
```

- This tells git to use only commit B and C in from the history
- Save your changes
- Close editor

### Difficulty

Experience with `git rebase [branch name]`
( For the *worst case* scenario )

### Worst case

Case: The commit you removed was not independent of the other commits. And now *git rebase* wants stuff from you, you have no idea about.
Solution: Reverse the process with `git rebase --abort`